# Animation in Javascript with two pictures

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am a beginner in JavaScript and am trying to write animation code for a JavaScript game. The idea of my animation code is that every 30fps, a new picture (there are two - `diamond1` and `diamond2`) will be loaded, which makes the diamond "shine".

Here is part of my code:

```
this.currentAnimationState = 0
const spriteWidth = 32
this.animationSprites = [
    { x: 0 * spriteWidth, y: 0 * spriteWidth }
]
this.FrameCount = 0
this.fps = 30
} 

...

draw() {
        this.game.engine.drawImage(
            this.game.assets.diamond1,
            256,
            256,
            0,
            0,
            this.x,
            this.y,
            this.width
        ) // Diamond
    }

    updateDiamond(){
        if ( this.currentAnimationState =
        (this.currentAnimationState % this.FrameCount === 0){

} 
    }
```

I have a problem in the `draw()` function - I do not know how to add `diamond2` to `assets`, that should be loaded.
Also in `updateDimond()` function, I am not sure if my if statement is correct, and I do not know how I should finish it so that the picture will be updated.

UPDATE - currentAnimationState will be not incremented in missing code. Here is my assetLoader class:

```
export default class AssetLoader {
    loadAsset(name, url) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const image = new Image()
            image.src = url
            image.addEventListener('load', function() {
                return resolve({ name, image: this })
            })
            image.addEventListener('error', function() {
                return reject(new Error('Image did not load ' + url))
            })
        })
    }
loadAssets(assetsToLoad) {
        return Promise.all(
            assetsToLoad.map(asset => this.loadAsset(asset.name, asset.url))
        ).then(assets =>
            assets.reduceRight(
                (acc, elem) => ({ ...acc, [elem.name]: elem.image }),
                {}
            )
        )
    }
}
```

and the part of the code where the pictures which are used in the game are loaded:

```
function initWithAssets() {
    return new AssetLoader()
        .loadAssets([
            { name: 'stone', url: 'img/stone.png' },
            { name: 'dirt', url: 'img/soil2.png' },
            { name: 'dirt2', url: 'img/soil.png' },
            { name: 'diamond1', url: 'img/diamond1.png' },
            { name: 'diamond2', url: 'img/diamond2.png' },
            { name: 'wormw', url: 'img/worm1.png' },
            { name: 'worms', url: 'img/worm2.png' },
            { name: 'wormn', url: 'img/worm3.png' },
            { name: 'worme', url: 'img/worm4.png' },
            { name: 'molew', url: 'img/molew.png' },
            { name: 'molee', url: 'img/molee.png' },
        ])
        .then(assets => {
            return init(assets)
        })
        .catch(e => {
            console.error(e)
            return e
        })
}
```

Comment: You'd need to show us how diamond1 is loaded so we can tell you how to load diamond2. Then no, updateDiamond will do nothing after the first time it's called, except if somewhere in the missing code there is something that does increment currentAnimationState. And in draw, you'll want something more dynamic to set which source image to use. But all in all, your question as it stands falls in the misses an [MCVE] category of questions we can't give a proper to...

Comment: just make a gif :D